# Clang intrinsics for _mm256_shuffle_epi32

Tags: c++11, clang++, avx2

I am trying to compile some AVX2 code on Clang. However, it seems that clangs implementation of AVX2 is not compliant with Intel's intrinsic documentation.

This code

```
static inline __m256i maskCompress(const Vec4q& input, const uint8_t bitMask) {
    const int mask = maskCompressLUT4[bitMask];
#ifdef __AVX2__
    __m256i retval = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(input, mask);
    return retval;
#else ...
}
```

Results in:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type '__m256i' with an rvalue of type 'void'
```

And if try to just do the shuffle, I get:

```
error: index for __builtin_shufflevector must be a constant integer
```

According to this:

https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-04EC3E64-539B-414D-AE0E-D2B2DDBDB401.htm

It should be perfectly viable to shuffle with control masks only known at runtime (if it wasn't, there would not be much point of shuffle?). Shuffle should also be returning a `__m256i`, but clang seems to think the method returns  nothing.

I am including `<immintrin.h>`.

I tried permute too, seems similarly broken. Any ideas how to make shuffle work as specified in Clang?

Comment: "The shuffle value must be an immediate" = encoded in the opcode = only compile time constants.

Comment: Damn... So I will have to use the variable shuffle?

Comment: Yes, you need `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32`.

Comment: But why does clang complain about the return value being void?

Comment: Does it still complain about this if you pass a literal constant for the second parameter ?

Comment: Yep. Still complains even with a literal

Comment: What's a `Vec4q` ? Is that something from Agner Fog's library ? What happens if you pass an `__m256i` as the first parameter instead ?